# Instantiate a Windows Forms control in WPF without default constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, custom-controls, windowsformshost

I am trying to host a custom Windows Forms control in WPF. My custom control does not have a public constructor, and it has a static `Create()` method which looks something like this:

```
public abstract class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{
  internal MyCustomControl(...) {  }

  public static MyCustomControl Create(SomeEnum kind)
  {
    switch (kind)
    {
      case SomeEnum.Kind1:
        return new MySuperCustomControl(...);
      ...
    }
```

What I want to do is instantiate this custom control in WPF and then have it hosted in [`WindowsFormsHost`](http://nayyeri.net/host-windows-forms-controls-in-wpf), but I obviously can't add an abstract class:

```
 <wfi:WindowsFormsHost Width="250" Height="150">
  <my:MyCustomControl x:Name="customControl" />  <-- doesn't work
</wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
```

Is there a way I could add it into the "Host" via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't host control without public constructor in XAML.
You can try two way:

1. define name for your
   WindowsFormsHost and set Child
   property of WindowsFormsHost to your
   instance from static Create() in C#
   code. for example in initialize (or
   load) method. - it is simple way.
2. try to bind Child property of WindowsFormsHost to Create() method.
   Frankly, I don't know or this
   approach will be work... but you can
   try :).. how bind to method in XAML?
   you can read - [this](http://rredcat.blogspot.com/search/label/Bind%20to%20a%20Method) or try to
   look in msdn or google :)

Answer (score 1):

Found it, it's the [`WindowsFormsHost.Child`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.child.aspx) property.